# Postgres database compatibility between 13.8 and 13.11?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to restore a Postgres database dump.
The restore fails.  I'm not sure how to find the logs that tells me why it fails.

The database was made using Postgres 13.8.  My current install is 13.11.

Is this the cause of the restore failure?  And if so, is there a migration script that I could restore this database to 13.11?

Comment: pg_restore prints any errors to screen. If you are using a different tool then you are going to find the error or at the very least say what tool you are using if you expect anyone to be able to help

Comment: 1) From Postgres 10 on the versioning numbering is X.x where X is major version and x is minor version, where minor versions are bug/security fix releases. As such you can upgrade a database in place from 13.8 --> 13.11 without a dump/restore. That also means you can restore a 13.8 dump file to a 13.11 database. 2) What OS are you on and how did you install Postgres?  Add answers as update to question.